# joining 3 field in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, union

i have a this sql query using uin

```
    SELECT Sum(scores_ofexpert.score) FROM scores_ofexpert
    WHERE scores_ofexpert.user_id = '30' AND scores_ofexpert.score > '0'
    UNION
    SELECT Sum(scores_ofexpert.score) FROM scores_ofexpert
    WHERE scores_ofexpert.user_id = '30' AND scores_ofexpert.score < '0'
    UNION
    SELECT Sum(scores_ofexpert.score) FROM scores_ofexpert
    WHERE scores_ofexpert.user_id = '30'
```

this extract sum of negative scores,sum of positive scoes and sum of all scores of a user;
like this

```
 -------------
 |-10        |
 -------------
 |30         |
 -------------
 |20         |
 -------------
```

but i want the result as this

```
 -------------------------------------
 |n_sum      |p_sum      |sum        |
 -------------------------------------    
 |-10        |30         |20         |
 -------------------------------------
```

how do it?

Comment: You need to learn when to use `UNION ALL` too (TIP: it is faster then plain `UNION`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CASE`

```
 SELECT
 SUM(CASE WHEN s.score < 0 THEN s.score ELSE 0 END) n_sum,
 SUM(CASE WHEN s.score > 0 THEN s.score ELSE 0 END) p_sum,
 SUM(s.score) `sum`
 FROM scores_ofexpert s
   WHERE s.user_id = '30'
```

Comment: Its useful for sql server

Answer (score 0):

This is another answer

```
SELECT
( SELECT Sum(scores_ofexpert.score)  
    FROM scores_ofexpert  
    WHERE   
    scores_ofexpert.user_id = '30' AND 
    scores_ofexpert.score > '0'
) p_sum,
(       SELECT
        Sum(scores_ofexpert.score)
        FROM
        scores_ofexpert
        WHERE
        scores_ofexpert.user_id = '30' AND
        scores_ofexpert.score < '0'
) n_sum,
(       SELECT
        Sum(scores_ofexpert.score)
        FROM
        scores_ofexpert
        WHERE
        scores_ofexpert.user_id = '30'
) sum_all
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
 sum(if(s.score > '0',s.score, 0)) as  p_sum,
 sum(if(s.score < '0',s.score, 0)) as n_sum,
 SUM(s.score) as t_sum
 FROM scores_ofexpert s
   WHERE s.user_id = '30'
```